# jQuery finds no elements with specified id

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net-core

I've started using .NET Core to develop ASP sites and so I wanted to try something I haven't tried before. I am going to make a global object that I can call functions on from any page since I have a setup in which all pages use a specific layout file.

So I got this setup here:

```
<html>
<header>
    <css and meta stuff>
</header>
<body>
    <navbar....>
    <sidebar...>
    <div id="render-body">@RenderBody</div>
    <layout-footer....>
    <script inclusions>
</body>
</html>
```

When `@RenderBody()` is called, an HTML page is served as the actual page that the browser receives, in-between the two div tags.

What I'm trying to then do, is to make a function which can hide the sidebar because you might not always need it and as such it should be possible to simply hide it.

So I wrote the following piece of code:

```
var UniHub = {
    ToggleContextSidebar: function () {
        var $sidebarAndBody = $("#render-body", "#context-sidebar");
        $sidebarAndBody.toggleClass("hide-context-sidebar");
    }
};
```

Which in theory should work right? But it doesn't. The code is called just fine, but #render-body and #context-sidebar are not found. When I debug I find that the `$sidebarAndBody` element has a length of 0. So toggleClass() doesn't actually apply a class to any of the two divs.

They are present at the time I press my test button:[image]

So why could this be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're closing `#context-sidebar` then opening `#render-body`, so `#render-body` is not in the context (inside) of `#context-sidebar`. Hence no matching element.

EDIT: if you want both elements you could do:

`$sidebarAndBody = $("#render-body, #context-sidebar");`

If you only want to target the sidebar just use `$("#context-sidebar");`

EDIT: showing jQuery context:

```js
console.log("# of body elems inside html:", $("body", "html").length);
console.log("# of body elems inside head:", $("body", "head").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The two are not supposed to be in the same div though. Why would that matter if the script is run on the parent site rather than the requesting site?

Comment: I'm not talking about where the script is run, I'm only talking about the document I see, and $(elem, context) only selects elem inside context: see http://api.jquery.com/jquery/

Comment: Okay. I watched a Pluralsight video where it was explained as a multi-selector. Is that wrong?

Comment: If you want to grab both elements, don't use 2 arguments. The comma should go inside the quotes: `$("#render-body, #context-sidebar");`

Comment: @FrankModica Oooh...syntax error...that's the actual correct answer. Make it an answer if you want some points.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think of the multi-selector (array), which indeed is what Frank just wrote.

Comment: @yezzz - Your answer made me realize what was actually wrong. I don't mind if you update yours and get the points.

Comment: I'm not sure what code gives you a syntax error. You didn't include jquery library on your page?

Comment: @yezzz No no, the error was that the comma should go in the string, instead of between the two strings.

Comment: Something like `$("body", "head").toggleClass("whatever")` toggles 0 elements, but doesn't give an error... so you may want to recheck.

Comment: You're still passing 2 arguments. It should be one argument with a comma. `$("body, head")`

Comment: @FrankModica What frank said, yea

Comment: @FrankModica we're aware of that, but I read Vipar is getting an error on his original code which is `$(elem, context)` which should not give an error even if that matches 0 elements.

Comment: @yezzz The problem was that I used the code wrong. I wasn't even aware `$(elem, context)` was something I could do. I thought I was just selecting 2 different elements at the same time, as I wanted to. But Frank spotted the error. Instead of elem and context, it should just be a single parameter passed as a string, that mentions both elements I'm looking for.

Comment: By "syntax error" I think @Vipar just meant that it was the wrong syntax for this particular task. There was no actual error.

Comment: Lol yeah I was just about to ask if it was just an english grammar problem ;)

Comment: well I replaced  `.add` with the selector array. See you around guys :)